# Sphinx API (PHP) - Only returns a maximum of 20 'displaying matches'

Tags: php, sphinx

I've got the latest version of Sphinx installed (using with the Sphinx PHP API) it all setup & configured correctly AFAIK however when I use search daemom no matter what keywords I choose I always get a maximum of '20 displaying matches'

Is there a setting I need to alter?

Comment: doh... found it!
$cl->SetLimits(0,10000);

Comment: You should add it as an answer - and accept your own answer. Then at least the question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the docs:

"There are two places where the default limit of at most 1000 matches per query is imposed.

First, on the server side, you have to change **max_matches** settings in **sphinx.conf**, and restart the searchd. (With 0.9.9 and above, you can simply reload the config file using SIGHUP.)

Second, there's also a **3rd argument** to **SetLimits() API call** that also defaults to 1000 and must be raised. (With SphinxSE, use "maxmatches" option.)"

Link for doc : http://sphinxsearch.com/info/faq/#max-matches

Hope this will help !!

Answer (score 1):

max_matches will only allow Sphinx to fetch more results as a whole, but it won't **display** more results.

To do this, you should use the parameter 'limit' e.g. :

```
SELECT * ...
WHERE query = "keyword;limit=1000";
```